# How to create PEM file for RSA keys

Tags: ios, objective-c, cryptography, rsa, pem

I have generated public key for RSA using SecKeyWrapper class provided by Apple. How can I create PEM file to save this key in that file? Do we have any library or framework for this?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

```
openssl rsa -in ~/.ssh/id_rsa -outform pem > id_rsa.pem
chmod 700 id_rsa.pem
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just pasting code. Adding a small explanation will work wonders.